# PersistJS not working, some function is not defined when removing item?

Tags: javascript

I used PersistJS to save session variables, please [refer here](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557)

And I have the following as my code to test:

```
<body onload='load_data();'>

<script type='text/javascript'>

   // global object
    var store;

    function load_data() {
      // load persistent store after the DOM has loaded
      store = new Persist.Store('My Application');

   store.set('some_key', 'this is a bunch of persistent data');

      // get value from store and prompt user
    store.get('some_key', function(ok, val) {
      if (ok)
        alert('some_key = ' + val);
    });

    //remove value
    store.remove('some_key');

    //display removed store
       store.get('some_key', function(ok, val) {
      if (ok)
        alert('some_key = ' + val);
    });

    }

</script>

</body>
```

The code worked fine retrieving the set value, however, when removing the item, the script crash and the error is as follows:

```
TypeError: this.getItem is not a function
val = this.getItem(key);
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

get takes 1 parameter.

---

Here is the definition:

```
function (key){key=this.key(key);return this.store.getItem(key);}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in persist.js

change line 479

val = this.getItem(key); to val = this.**store**.getItem(key);